# Concatenate a changeable string using JavaScript executor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have a String variable that takes some ID's from an excel.

```
String answerID = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2));
```

I am using JavaScript executor to change each time the ID but it seems that the concatenation isn't the right one:

```
je.executeScript("document.querySelector('.js-react-thanks-button-answer-id-"+answerID+" button').click()");
 System.out.println("Thank you checked for link " + link);
je.executeScript("document.querySelector('div[data-answer-id='" + answerID + "'] .sg-rate-box__filled-stars span:last-of-type svg').click()");
System.out.println("5 stars for link " + link);
```

can you give me a small help please?

Comment: You should remove Selenium and probably add Apache POI in tags....

Comment: @MichaelWölm OP is using `executeScript()` IMO, `selenium` tag is fair.

Comment: @cristinasandu Please avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the symbol ' with slash(\)  as given below

```
je.executeScript("document.querySelector('div[data-answer-id=\'" + answerID + "\'] .sg-rate-box__filled-stars span:last-of-type svg').click()");
System.out.println("5 stars for link " + link);
```

Answer (score 0):

First add below dependency in pom :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

and then proceed like below code :

```
js.executeScript(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeEcmaScript("document.querySelector('.js-react-thanks-button-answer-id-"+answerID+" button').click()"));
js.executeScript(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeEcmaScript("document.querySelector('div[data-answer-id='" + answerID + "'] .sg-rate-box__filled-stars span:last-of-type svg').click()"));
```

Hope that helps you.
For escaping javascript you can use like :

```
js.executeScript(StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript("document.querySelector('.js-react-thanks-button-answer-id-"+answerID+" button').click()"));
js.executeScript(StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript("document.querySelector('div[data-answer-id='" + answerID + "'] .sg-rate-box__filled-stars span:last-of-type svg').click()"));
```